# Validity of law of charge conservation in charging by induction, earthing

Tags: electrostatics, conservation-laws, charge

Charging by induction and earthing gives an object a net charge but why does the law of charge conservation still hold in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is still valid.

Actually we consider the earth as an embodiment of negative charge, so huge an embodiment that addition or subtraction of any number of electrons to it cannot change its negative charge. But if we leave out this assumption and consider that the number of electrons is discrete, then you will understand that no. of electrons leaving\entering the conductor due to induction followed by grounding is equal to the no. of electrons gained\lost by the earth.

Hence charge conservation is valid.